# App Engine session cookie expiration

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session-cookies

I'm developing an Java App Engine project with multiple modules. I have enabled the sessions in the appengine-web.xml for the default module:

```
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
```

When i open the default module in the browser; a session is created:

Upon closing the browser. The session is gone. When inspecting the cookies in the browser I only see 1 cookie for the domain:

```
JSESSIONION-c73210e91f2dc1e586e87edd793da6dc
```

with an **expiration** set to the **end of the session**. In the datastore there are entities created of the kind _ah_SESSION (I also see them in the memcache). So App Engine has enabled the sessions but is not giving me a persisting cookie with a default expiration of +30 minutes.

Is there something I am overseeing here ?

**Update:**
I have set the session timeout parameter in the web.xml just to be sure. But still no persisting cookie:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>100</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: isn't `end of the session` equal to `+30 minutes`?

Comment: It's a cookie with no expiration date. Meaning it will be deleted when the user closes the browser.